# View without iterating through IEnumerable model C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm new to MVC, got a problem trying to create a simple UI. I've to display the model in a view and support pagination.
My view would display each column and below the name of the column there must be either a text box or drop down to perform filtering of data.

My model is as below

```
 public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Full Name")]
    public string fullName{ get; set; }

    [DisplayName("State")]
    public string adressState{ get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Grade")]
    public string grade{ get; set; }

   public MultiSelectList grades{ get; set; }
   public MultiSelectList adressState{ get; set; }
   }
```

I'm passing IEnumerable model to view and my view should be as below

```
<div class="dataTable">
<table id="mainTable">
    <thead>
        <tr >
            <th ></th>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fullName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.address)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.grade)
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <th>
                <img src="~/Images/someimage.png" alt="Options" height="25" width="25" />

            </th>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
            <th>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.name, new { onkeyup = "handleKeyPress(event, this)", placeholder = "Search", @class = "TextBox searchProperties" })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.fullName, new { onkeyup = "handleKeyPress(event, this)", placeholder = "Search", @class = "TextBox searchProperties"})
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.adressState, Model.adressStateItemList as MultiSelectList, new { onchange = "handleDropdownChange()", @id = "adressStateDropDown", 
                @class = "searchProperties" })

            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.gradeItem, Model.gradeItemList as MultiSelectList, new { onchange = "handleDropdownChange()", @id = "gradeDropDown",
               @class = "searchProperties" })
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableResults">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_StudentPartial", Model);}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

student partial must have a for each to loop through the model data and display.
I'm unable to bind my model to view and display data as my main view expects a model to display text box for property and partial view expects a IEnumerable of model. I've tried 
    @Html.Partial("_studentPartial", new IEnumerable<.solution.ViewModel>) 
but does not work. Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: If the view being shown has a model of a *single instance* of something, how do you expect to derive a *list* of something?  You can turn a basket of apples into individual apples, but you can't turn an individual apple into a basket of apples.  Also, you can't create a `new` instance of an *interface*, only a *class*.

Comment: The view you're showing implies that the model is a single instance, not a collection.  And if the model were a collection, why would you need to convert it to a collection in the inner view?  This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If the model is a collection then how do any of the HTML helpers already in this view work at all?  There also appear to be references to properties which aren't even on the model at all, as well as the model appears to have multiple properties with the same name.  This code can't even compile, for multiple reasons.  You may want to back up a bit and go back to some MVC tutorials.

Comment: `"could you suggest a way to implement my requirement"` - That's a *very* broad question.  Stack Overflow can help answer specific questions, but not provide you with entire tutorials custom-made for your needs.  What you have here, quite honestly, is a mess of code that won't work for multiple reasons.  "Implementing your requirement" isn't going to happen until you get a handle on the basics.  Don't just dive in and build a complex page with no experience.  Start small and build up to it, one small feature at a time.

Comment: Well!! I didnt request for a custom made tutorial.If I was not clear, my requirement here is just to have model on main view and  pass a IEnumerable model to a partial view.  I just meant to ask if that is possible in anyway? Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Well, yes, it's possible to pass a collection to a view (as that view's model), display a single item from that collection, and pass the collection to another child view.  Start by creating a view, passing it a collection, and displaying an item from within that collection.  Don't even worry about the child view until you can successfully make the main view.

Answer (score 0):

The partial view should not be bound to an `IEnumerable` if its intent is to display a single item. It should be bound to a single model instance.

If the main view is bound to `IEnumerable<ViewModel>` then bind the partial to `ViewModel`.

Then in your main view,

```
foreach(var item in Model)
{
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_StudentPartial", item);}
}
```